# how to do a many to many model for this project in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble creating a many to many model for my project.

Basically i have a Matches & Teams model.

Teams are created prior to the Matches.

Once the match is created then i would like to add teams to it.

Match can have many teams, Teams can have many matches.

I'm currently adding teams via nested_form and adding multiple teams at once.

When submitting the form, i get an error expecting the team to be in a relationship already with the match.

I can do this with a many to one relationship but it fails with many-to-many, was wondering if there was any way to do it without doing a custom route.

Below is the form, controllers are as per default values.

Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@match) do |f| %>
  <% if @match.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@match.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this match from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @match.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :teams, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label "Team Name:" %>
    <%= builder.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_team_name_teams_path, :update_elements => {:id => "##{form_tag_id(builder.object_name, :id)}" },:class => "input-small",:placeholder => "Search" %>
  <%= builder.hidden_field :id %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add raw('<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>'), :teams, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do your model files look like? You might need to do a `has_many..., :through...` and use a separate match_team join table. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: yeah i have all that, like i said, i'm already doing the same thing but with a one to many association it works fine, but the issue is the many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Using a join model, the `has_many :through` macro and the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` macro you can do something like the following.

```
class Match
  has_many :competitions                    
  has_many :teams, :through => :competitions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams      
end 

class Competition                           
  belongs_to :match                         
  belongs_to :team                          
end 

class Team
  has_many :competitions                    
  has_many :matches, :through => :competitions
end
```

Just make sure your form is set up to send the following data structure as `params` when the request reaches the `create` or `update` controller.

```
params => {                                
  :match => {
    # ...

    :teams_attributes => [                  
      { :name => 'Foo', :color => 'blue' },
      { :name => 'Bar', :color => 'green' },
      # ...
    ]
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i currently have, but there is a problem. It looks for the association upon creating or updating a match. remember i'm not creating the team, is already there, i'm just passing the id of the team and name to the post/put request. on the teams controller if i do this Matches.teams.build then this wont work when i'm creating teams on their own without any associations.

Comment: Sounds like you're actually trying to create a new object of the join model then, in my example a new `Competition` object. This will mean creating a form for the user to select existing `Team` objects (which I think you already do), then send a `POST` request to the `CompetitionsController` in order to call its `create` action. In there you can query for the existing `Match` and `Team` objects and create a new `Competition` object, creating the new association.

Comment: how would i handle then that there are only two teams max? also would this be handled restufully or do i need to make do a manual loop to iterate through the teams?

Comment: will the competitions controller handle the save as a rest? i guess i'm asking how the controller create and update method should look.

Comment: It would still be RESTful. Your resources can look something like `/matches/:id/competitions/new`, `/matches/:id/competitions/:id` and so on; You would nest `resources :competitions` inside the `resources :matches` block in your `config/routes.rb`. In the controller actions you should set up the form so `param[:competition][:teams]` would contain the array of two teams, and `param[:match_id]` is the id assigned for you by rails. Now you just find the match, iterate through the teams and create or update your competition records. That's one way to do it at least.

Comment: Handling max of two teams can be handled with validations in the `Match` model.

Comment: what would the controller look like?

Comment: I pretty much described it in my previous comment. Find the `Match` object. Then iterate through the team ids (or names) in the `param`. For each team id/name find the `Team` object. Create a new `Competition` object scoped to your `Match` object. Assign the `Team` object to it and save.

Comment: hey, i think i got everything but i can't iterate through the teams array with this 'params[:competition][:teams_attributes][:id]